# PHP mySQL Error with select query

Tags: php, mysql

Few others have got this same problem at the outset, however, I'm repeating this question because mine seems to be specific to EMail IDs.

I have a query that retrieves the password given a specific email id as input. THis is my query

```
Select Password from userauth where user_name in (select id from users where email = 's.sriram@example.com')
```

This query executes without any problem when done from phpMyAdmin.

However, it doesn't work when I do it through a php script. That php script is as follows:

```
<?php

// Grab User submitted information
$email = $_POST["users_email"];
$pass = $_POST["users_pass"];

// Connect to the database
$con= mysql_connect("localhost","root","sriram123");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
// Select the database to use
mysql_select_db("mydb",$con);

echo "Select Password from userauth where user_name in (select id from users where email = '$email')";

$result = mysql_query("Select Password from userauth where user_name in (select id from users where email = $email)");

if($result === FALSE) {
    echo "Error Occured. ";
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['Password'];
}


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Now, I get an error message like this when I execute it:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@example.com)' at line 1

I am new to PHP, and i'm just not sure why this thing works in phpMyAdmin but fails to work in my PHP script.

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around the variable? $email => '$email'

Answer (score 6):

[image: xkcd]

It looks like you didn't put the proper quotes around the variable, but you should use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string) to make sure it's actually safe to use in a query.

Answer (score 2):

1) Use PDO

2) Escape MYSQL names (Select Password from -> Select `Password` from)

3) Quote variables ($email -> '$email')

4) Never expose your password (`$con= mysql_connect("localhost","root","PASSWORD");`)

Start with this :)

Comment: 5) Never use such a simple password anyway XD

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("Select Password from userauth where user_name in
    (select id from users where email = $email)");
```

If $email is `a@b.com` it would be like:

```
$result = mysql_query("Select Password from userauth where user_name in
    (select id from users where email = a@b.com)");
```

You are missing the `''` around the e-mail address, as its a string.

Also, always use `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape every external string put into your query, otherwise your site will be vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the correct quotes around the `$email` variable. Try wrapping them in single quotes.

Change your code to:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email); //escaping
$query = "
SELECT Password
FROM userauth
WHERE user_name IN
    (SELECT id
     FROM users
     WHERE email = '$email')
     ";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Also, your MySQL query, as it currently stands, is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), and you should look into [escaping user input](http://bobby-tables.com). Better yet, stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and switch to [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo).